# What are the downsides of using IPv6 Multicast for majority of all communication including one-to-one?

Tags: routing, ipv6, multicast

Given IPv6 Multicast allows for a sub-pub communication model, it seems like a no-brainer for the vast majority of communication, but its very rarely used beyond video streaming, and I'd like to know if this is because its only efficient for large groups or if its just because its not well understood and Unicast/Anycast are easier to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Multicast is suitable for traffic where everyone receives same data at the same time. Majority of internet communication is not like that. For example, all web traffic is initiated by requests from users, and server replies to those requests.